# View not updating during a transition

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I need your help to understand an issue I'm having. I can't manage to make a view redraws its body just before a transition animation. Take a look at this simple example:

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var condition = true
    @State private var fgColor = Color.black

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Group {
                if condition {
                    Text("Hello")
                        .foregroundColor(fgColor)
                } else {
                    Text("World")
                }
            }
            .transition(.slide)
            .animation(.easeOut(duration: 3))

            Button("TAP") {
                fgColor = .red
                condition.toggle()
            }
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

What I expected from this example was: when I tap on the button the view creates its body again and the text "Hello" becomes red. Now, the view creates its body another time and the transition happens. Instead, it seems that SwiftUI merges the two state changes somehow and only the second one is considered. The result is that the transition happens, but the text "Hello" won't change its color.

[image]

How can I manage a situation like this in SwiftUI? Is there a way to tell the framework to update the two state changes separately? Thank you.

**EDIT** for @Asperi:

I tried your code but it doesn't work. The result is still the same. This is the complete example with your code:

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var condition = true
    @State private var fgColor = Color.black

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            VStack {
                if condition {
                    Text("Hello")
                        .foregroundColor(fgColor)
                                .transition(.slide)
                } else {
                    Text("World")
                        .transition(.slide)
                }
            }
            .animation(.easeOut(duration: 3))

            Button("TAP") {
                fgColor = .red
                condition.toggle()
            }
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

And this is the result (on iPhone 12 Mini iOS 14.1):

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a possible solution:

```
struct ContentView: View {

    @State private var condition = true
    @State private var fgColor = Color.black

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Group {
                if condition {
                    Text("Hello")
                        .foregroundColor(fgColor)
                } else {
                    Text("World")
                }
            }
            .transition(.slide)
            .animation(.easeOut(duration: 3))

            Button("TAP") {
                fgColor = .red

                withAnimation {
                    condition.toggle()
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The idea here is that you propagate the transition that was caused by `condition` change by changing it inside `withAnimation` (which is delayed compared to the foreground color change with no animation).

Comment: using extra animation in action of Button for making delay! why not **DispatchQueue** after a deadline? seems un-necessary use of **withAnimation** in your code! Because we have already animation on VStack!

Comment: Yes, that's right but an answer with **DispatchQueue** was already there so you can think of it as another possible solution.

Comment: Well... this solution is not bad at all, actually. In the button closure you are basically saying: "I want the `fgColor` to change *without any animation* and I want to animate everything that is based on the `condition` value", which is exactly what I was looking for. Also, consider that you can remove the `.animation(.easeOut(duration: 3))` line and everything still works as expected, so you don't even have an extra "animation instruction".

Comment: Thanks @matteopuc, yes actually removing `.animation(.easeOut(duration: 3))` line makes this even clearer.

Answer (score 2):

It's impossible to do what you want with just modifiers.

Because when change the view state, the code block with `Text("Hello")` doesn't get's called, and that's the reason it starts disappearing with transition you've specifier(because this view is missing in the view hierarchy)

So the best way you can do it is implementing your custom transition. At first you need to create a ViewModifier with your desired behavior:

```
struct ForegroundColorModifier: ViewModifier {
    var foregroundColor: Color
    
    func body(content: Content) -> some View {
        content
            // for some reason foregroundColor for text is not animatable by itself, but can animate with colorMultiply
            .foregroundColor(.white)
            .colorMultiply(foregroundColor)
    }
}
```

Then create a Transition using this modifier - here you need to specify modifiers for two states:

```
extension AnyTransition {
    static func foregroundColor(active: Color, identity: Color) -> AnyTransition {
        AnyTransition.modifier(
            active: ForegroundColorModifier(foregroundColor: active),
            identity: ForegroundColorModifier(foregroundColor: identity)
        )
    }
}
```

Combine color transition with a slide one:

```
.transition(
    AnyTransition.slide.combined(
        with: .foregroundColor(
            active: .red,
            identity: .black
        )
    )
)
```

Finally If you need color change only on disappearing, use asymmetric transition:

```
.transition(
    .asymmetric(
        insertion: .slide,
        removal: AnyTransition.slide.combined(
            with: .foregroundColor(
                active: .red,
                identity: .black
            )
        )
    )
)
```

Full code:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var condition = true
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Group {
                if condition {
                    Text("Hello")
                    
                } else {
                    Text("World")
                }
            }
            .transition(
                .asymmetric(
                    insertion: .slide,
                    removal: AnyTransition.slide.combined(
                        with: .foregroundColor(
                            active: .red,
                            identity: .black
                        )
                    )
                )
            )
            
            Button("TAP") {
                withAnimation(.easeOut(duration: 3)) {
                    condition.toggle()
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I'm not sure why specifying `.animation` after `.transition` doesn't work in this case, but changing state inside `withAnimation` block works as expected

[image: Final result]

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it's very interesting. Actually I wouldn't want the "Hello" to animate between black and red, I'd want the "Hello" to immediately become red and then the animation should start (it's written in the question). Anyway, it's just a matter of taking your `ForegroundColorModifier` and change the body to `content.foregroundColor(foregroundColor)` and it works.

Answer (score 1):

The main issue is in using `Group` - it is not a container, instead use some real container and apply transitions to views directly, like

[image: demo]

```
var body: some View {
    VStack {
        VStack {
            if condition {
                Text("Hello")
                    .foregroundColor(fgColor)
                            .transition(.slide)
            } else {
                Text("World")
                    .transition(.slide)
            }
        }
        .animation(.easeOut(duration: 3))

        Button("TAP") {
            fgColor = .red
            condition.toggle()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Mmh... I've just tried your solution, I don't know why but it doesn't work for me. If I literally copy/paste your code the result is the same as my gif in the question. What's your environment? I'm on Xcode 12.2, iPhone 12 Pro Max with iOS 14.2 Simulator.

Comment: I'll try on iOS 14.1, I'll let you know.

Comment: It's really strange. As you can see from my EDIT even with your code on iOS 14.1 I'm getting the same "wrong" result.

Comment: Mmh... looking at your GIF there's something strange. It starts with the black "world", but according to my example it should start with the black "Hello" (which should turn red on the first tap). Please, consider copy/pasting my whole example from my EDIT. Thank you.

Comment: Hi Asperi, did you get the chance to explore this issue? Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

The most easier and logical way of making your code work, updating View before Animation take the control.

---

[image]

### Version 1.0.0:

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State private var condition = true
    @State private var fgColor = Color.black
    
    var body: some View {
        
        VStack(spacing: 40.0) {
            
            Group {
                
                if condition {
                    
                    Text("Hello")
                        .foregroundColor(fgColor)
                    
                }
                else {
                    
                    Text("World")
                }
                
            }
            .transition(.slide)
            .animation(.easeOut(duration: 3))
            
            
            Button("TAP") {
                
                fgColor = .red
                
                DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: DispatchTime.now() + DispatchTimeInterval.milliseconds(50)) { condition.toggle() }
                
            }
            
        }
    }
}
```

### Version 2.0.0:

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State private var condition: Bool = true
    @State private var fgColor: Color = Color.green
    @State private var startTransition: Bool = Bool()
    
    var body: some View {
        
        VStack(spacing: 40.0) {
            
            Group {
                
                if condition {
                    
                    Text("Hello")
                        .foregroundColor(fgColor)
                    
                }
                else {
                    
                    Text("World")
                }
                
            }
            .transition(.slide)
            .animation(.easeOut(duration: 3))
            .onChange(of: startTransition) { _ in condition.toggle() }
            
            
            Button("TAP") {
                
                if fgColor == Color.red { fgColor = Color.green } else { fgColor = Color.red }
                
                startTransition.toggle()
                
            }
            
        }
    }
}
```

---

Comment: To be honest I don't like the solution with the delay. Let's say it's not something I'd put in a production environment. Your second solution, instead, is really interesting. Thank you.

Answer (score -2):

Try this,

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var condition = true
    @State private var fgColor = Color.black
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            HStack {
                Text("Hello")
                    .foregroundColor(fgColor)
                if !condition {
                    Text("World")
                }
            }
            .transition(.slide)
            .animation(.easeOut(duration: 3))
            
            Button("TAP") {
                fgColor = .red
                condition.toggle()
            }
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

Comment: Your solution doesn't actually answer the question. In the question we have an if/else statement to show either the "Hello" or the "World" word. In your solution there's the "Wello" word and an if statement to show the "World" word. It's a different scenario and doesn't work as a solution for the question (if you put an if/else in your code you'll see the same exact bug I'm experiencing in the question).